# Preference activity inside an Alert Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-preferences, preferencescreen

Can I inflate PreferenceScreen inside an alert dialog?

This is what I've tried:

```
final LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
final View myDialog = factory.inflate(R.xml.prefScr, null);
final Dialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("This is Dialog")
    .setView(myDialog)
    .create();
```

this gives me exception:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class PreferenceScreen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to use a `PreferenceScreen` outside of a `PreferenceActivity` like this...but here are a few alternatives:

1) Make the `Activity` appear as a dialog by using a style in your `Manifest`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyPrefsActivity"
    android:label=""
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
</activity>
```

2) Use an `AlertDialog` as you currently are but inflate it with your own custom layout that has the same features as you `PreferenceScreen` does. Then you would have to manage the getting and setting of preferences manually.

3) Just use a `PreferenceActivity` with its own `PreferenceDialog`. This might not really be the same thing that you want, but using a `PreferenceActivity` will save you a lot of the work of manually handling all of your preferences.